# How do I use "Use" correctly in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

"I'm not use to this city life" OR
"I'm not used to this city life" ?

Comment: "I'm not used to city life."

Answer (score 0):

The adjectival phrase "used to" is invariable: it cannot take the form "use to", even in questions ("Are you used to that?").

There is a verbal form which is similar, and may be confusing you. In current English, this phrasal verb also takes the form "used to", because it exists only in the past (it could be used in other tenses a couple of hundred years ago, but not today). But in the negative and interrogative it is "didn't use to" and "did you use to?".

Because the 'd' of "used" and the 't'" of "to" are homorganic, they are usually run together as effectively one word; so some people are unsure whether to spell it "use to" or "used to" (John Lawler treats it as one word and writes "useta") But traditionally it is always "used to" except in the cases I mentioned.